# Cosa sono le "impostarelle"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Vita pensava alle fiere di Minturno, ma quei ricordi sbiadivano, li afferrava appena, però anche la piazza di Minturno era bella, all’ombra del castello, con le pacchiane intovagliate di merletto e l’odore delle **impostarelle** con lo stoccafisso.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa sono le "impostarelle"? Non ho trovato il termine "impostarella" su nessun dizionario italiano, quindi immagino si tratti di un vocabolo di uso regionale. Tuttavia, non l'ho trovato neanche sul [vocabolario napolitano-italiano di Giuseppe Giacco](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/online-reference-works-on-italian-dialects-regional-terms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come riportato in questo [blog relativo alla cucina napoletana](https://www.scattidigusto.it/2017/01/18/pizzeria-napoli-enzo-coccia-vomero/), l’impostarella (nel testo mpustarella) è una sorta di antipasto o stuzzichino che consiste in una sorta di piccolo panino farcito nei modi più disparati.

Nel vocabolario da te citato si trova infatti il termine:

> **mpustarella**: f. colazione tipo sandwich.

Comment: Per quanto ho potuto capire, sono piccole nella pizzeria di cui parla l'articolo, ma non sempre.

Answer (score 1):

Si tratta dell'italianizzazione del termine napoletano "mpustarella". Ecco quello che Renato Casolaro spiega su [questo sito web](http://www.cinquecolonne.it/a-mpustarella.html) sul significato e origine di questo vocabolo, facendo riferimento a qualche dizionario dello studioso della lingua e la civiltà napoletana [Francesco D'Ascoli](https://nap.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francesco_D%27Ascoli), possibilmente il *Dizionario Etimologico Napoletano*:

> La ***mpustarella*** è, si sa, una “colazione fatta con pane e companatico”, è un “panino ripieno” (D’Ascoli), nel quale sia stato inserito (quasi “impostato” come una lettera nella buca, ci verrebbe da dire se volessimo indulgere al gioco di parole) una fetta di qualche salume e/o formaggio. 
>   Naturalmente, se invece del panino usiamo due fette di pane accostate, il risultato non cambia.
>   Ciò che connota la ***mpustarella*** non è solo il modo in cui viene fatta, ma anche l’ora, il momento, che può variare ma è sempre un momento lontano dai pasti principali: metà mattinata o metà pomeriggio (la “merendina” di oggi non ne è che il lontano discendente), e in qualche caso persino metà nottata (per gli insonni che nel silenzio della notte vagano tra il letto e il frigo in cerca di un qualche sollievo alle loro pene).
>   Insomma la ***mpustarella*** è quello che in italiano si chiama spuntino, che serve soprattutto a ***suppuntà***, ovvero a “sostenere” (quasi “puntare da sotto”), uno stomaco che brontola. È per questo che Enrico Malato, contestando alcune derivazioni invero poco fondate, faceva derivare la parola dal verbo ***mpustà*** in un senso traslato di “assestare”, “mettere a sesto”.
>   Il verbo effettivamente si adoperava già nell’Ottocento per indicare, tra l’altro, “appoggiare travi, archi etc.”, e infatti la ***mposta***, poco più d’un secolo fa, era “l’impostatura di un arco o di una volta” (Andreoli).
>   In questo senso dunque ***mpustarella*** deriverebbe da “impostare” nel senso di “mettere sotto”. È a questo che pensiamo quando parliamo di ***suppuntà ’o stommaco***.
>   Ma nel nostro caso c’è qualcosa (il companatico) che non si mette “sotto”, quanto piuttosto “in”, “dentro”, “in mezzo”. E *mpustà* significa anche “impostare” una lettera (ahimé anche questa oggi espressione in via di estinzione, giacché la posta ormai viaggia per lo più telematicamente), cioè appunto “mettere dentro”.
>   Proprio il D’Ascoli che abbiamo citato all’inizio vede la *mpustarella* come diminutivo di *mposta*, “dall’idea della fetta di companatico che viene inserita nel panino aperto”.
>   Perché la ***mposta***, nel napoletano moderno (del Nocevento, intendiamo), è la “suola di rinforzo che s’inserisce fra due altre”.
>   Dunque la ***mpustarella*** potrebbe anche venire dall’ambiente dei calzolai, i ***solachianielle***.
>   È d’obbligo una breve parentesi per avvertire chi non lo sapesse che il *solachianiello* (“che risuola pianelle”, scarpe) non va confuso con lo ***scarparo***. Quest’ultimo le scarpe le costruiva, mentre il *solachianiello* riparava le calzature. Il mestiere è ancora vivo, anche se meno diffuso di una volta, quando le scarpe si riparavano, si risuolavano, si rinforzavano perché se ne compravano molte di meno.
>   
>   Quanti di noi ricordano di aver portato a riparare delle scarpe che *tenevano famma*, come dicevamo scherzosamente quando si aprivano sul davanti (specie quelle dei ragazzi, che usavano giocare a pallone per strada) dopo che si era consumata la parte anteriore, perché quella parte anteriore della scarpa ci pareva simile a una bocca aperta pronta a mangiare!
>   
>   Era allora che il ***solachianiello*** inseriva una suoletta fra le due suole sul davanti per rinforzare il tutto (che poi sarebbe stato unificato col mastice e con quei chiodini microscopici detti da noi ***semmenzelle***, o forse con quegli altri chiodini dalla testa piatta e abnorme detti ***centrelle***).
>   
>   Ebbene, come non pensare che la *mposta* (dal latino ***impositam***, “posta dentro”) abbia dato luogo alla *mpustarella*, l’inserimento di una fetta di prosciutto o di salame fra le due “suole” costituite dalle due metà di un panino o dalle due fette di pane all’uopo tagliate?
>   
>   Il termine, il quale, come s’è già capito, è una formazione novecentesca (giacché i vocabolari dell’Ottocento non lo riportano), [...]

(Ho omesso l'ultima parte dell'articolo perché l'autore afferma che è pura fantasia).